# Is $\mathcal{F}$ sigma-field in $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that $\mathcal{F} = \left\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N}: A \quad \text{is finite set or } \quad X \setminus A \quad \text{is finite set} \right\}   $ is sigma-field in $\mathbb{N}$?

I suppose that it is not sigma-field, but I can't find counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $\{2n\} \in \mathcal F$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. Do we have $\bigcup_n \{2n\} \in \mathcal F$?

Comment: $\bigcup_n \{2n\}$ is not finite set (obviously). Furthermore $ \mathbb{N} \setminus \bigcup_n \{2n\}  =\bigcup_n \{2n +1\} $ which also is not finite. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$